# passing values into ConstructorInfo.Invoke

Tags: c#

I am using reflection to construct a class object which accepts an `int` as constructor parameter. I am using `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` to create the class.  Can any one please tell me  how can I pass a parameter to the constructor? I am trying the following method without luck

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Type typa = ass.GetType("Abc");
            Type[] types = new Type[1];
            types[0] = typeof(int);
            ConstructorInfo csInfo =typa.GetConstructor(types);
            int[] obj = {10};

            csInfo.Invoke(obj);
```

I get the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'object[]'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [signuature of `Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17.aspx) expects `object[]`. So give `object[]` to it.

```
object[] obj = {10};
csInfo.Invoke(obj);
```